# ASP.NET UpdatePanel Breaks When ScriptManager is in Master Page

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a .NET 4.0 web application with a simplified structure that looks like:
RootMaster (with ScriptManager) > ShipmentMaster > ContentPage > UpdatePanel

The UpdatePanel was recently added to reduce page flickering via partial page updates.  It's not working.  Instead, full postbacks/updates are happening.

I've set-up two scaled down versions of this with one (Ex1) mimicking the structure above, and one (Ex2) that looks like:
ContentPage (with ScriptManager) > UpdatePanel

It would seem that something about the Master/ScriptManager arrangement of the original (and Ex1) is breaking things, but I don't know what.

Any ideas?

Here is the relevant (I think, correct me if wrong) code for Ex1:

Root.master,

```
<body>
<form id="pageForm" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="SiteScriptManager" 
        runat="server" 
        AjaxFrameworkMode="Enabled" 
        EnablePartialRendering="True" 
        LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true"
        ScriptMode="Release"
        onasyncpostbackerror="SiteScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError" >
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.tools.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/json2.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/modernizr.custom.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/PFF.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
...
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx,

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Root.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pasha.OTTS.Web.FamiliesFirst.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="RootHeadContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="RootBodyContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dpShipments" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DataPager ID="dpShipments" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvShipments" PageSize="3" onprerender="dpShipments_PreRender">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField />
            <asp:NumericPagerField />
        </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
        <asp:ListView ID="lvShipments" runat="server" onpagepropertieschanging="lvShipments_PagePropertiesChanging">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="table-wrapper">
                <table class="results">
                    <tr>
                        <th>A</th>
                        <th>B</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td ><%#Eval("A")%></td>
                <td ><%#Eval("B")%></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <p>Async: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>  
        </p>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - I don't know who added it, or why (and I realize it wasn't shown in my original post), but the offensive code was on the following line:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Root.master.cs" Inherits="FamiliesFirst.Master.Root" ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

Specifically:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

Removing that made the problem go away.